# rsync in non-daemon

Tags: c, linux, rsync

I want to know how rsync works in non-daemon mode ,and what it is exactly ?

From rsync man pages , I came to know how daemon mode works .
I know something about daemon mode. Daemon is a process continuously listening for connections in background.

Now , the scene is ,I don't want to use Daemon mode ,as it will require some dedicated port always to be in listening.

I want to know,how does the client(say, local machine) in non-daemon mode technically invokes the rsync listener on server(say,remote machine) and vice versa?
The reason for this approach is that , **I don't want client should know the port number of server before-hand ** .
Any detail explanations will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you look into the source code of `rsync`?  Perhaps it is calling `daemon(3)` by default, or avoiding that call! You could also use `strace` to find out.

Comment: Without a daemon rsync just uses SSH/RSH.

Comment: Hey , Basile thanks for that.
My use of strace command is limited for tracing system calls and signals. But, my query asks , how to determine the port number of remote system in non-daemon mode ??
and yeah , I looked into code of rsync and that too was too complicated to find where daemon(3) is getting called. 
so , please explain how can I use strace for getting the solution to my original query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From rsync man-page:

> There  are  two  different  ways  for rsync to contact a remote
>   system:
>          using a remote-shell program as the transport (such as ssh or  rsh)  or
>          contacting  an  rsync daemon directly via TCP.

So in non-deamon mode you can use ssh to connect and update your clients. In this case the initial connection through ssh will setup the client side so that rsync can connect without knowing the port number.

Comment: hey perreal , I want to know in details how the ssh will setup client side in details.As in , exactly what procedure it undergoes to do the same ?

Answer (score 2):

This answers my question :

I found out how it invokes remote rsync in non-daemon mode.
on **Local side** : if command is :- rsync -avz -e ssh remoteuser@remotehost:/remote/dir /this/dir/ 
this command will **starts another process** on the local side as :-
**ssh -l remoteuser 192.168.xx.xxx -vlogDtprze.iLsf . /remote/dir**

This ssh command invokes **rsync on remote on remote box** as :
rsync --server -vlogDtprze.iLsf . /remote/dir/

and starts with arbitrary port no. but data communication occurs over ssh (port 22 needs to be open).

Answer (score 0):

Its call rsync over ssh in that case you don't need to run daemon

Comment: fine . but , I asked how ssh will know the port number of remote side ? technical details please.

Comment: rsync -avz -e ssh remoteuser@remotehost:/remote/dir /this/dir/

Comment: I found out how it invokes remote rsync in non-daemon mode.